# split queries with regex

Tags: python, sql-parser

#i am using regex to split this but i am getting wrong results.

```
import re

queries ="""
INSERT ignore into persons VALUES (15,'Tom D.', 'Erilchsen', 
'Skagen 21', 'Erlangen');
select * from persons;
"""

regex = "[;!]+?"
y = re.split(regex ,queries)
print(y)
print(len(y))
print(y[0])
```

output:

```
["\nINSERT ignore into persons VALUES (15,'Tom D.', 'Erilchsen', \n'Skagen 21', 'Erlangen')", '\nselect * from persons', '\n']
3
```

Comment: You didn't explain the expected result. Please share it. Is the issue the `\n` ?

Comment: use a _slice_ or a _split_ or provide a criteria for the matching

Comment: Why dont you just merge `quieries` into one line then run your regex? Even using `queries.replace("\n", "")`

Comment: no, the issue is the extra element in the list.
i have two queries but i am getting one extra element in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually need a regex for this:

```py
queries ="""
INSERT ignore into persons VALUES (15,'Tom D.', 'Erilchsen', 
'Skagen 21', 'Erlangen');
select * from persons;
"""

y = list(filter(None, queries.replace("\n", "").split(";")))
print(y)
print(len(y))
print(y[0])
```